# What's a popular phrase that means "a warning against doing something"?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, *the failure of the Prevention of Atrocities Act to change the social standing of Dalits is a [ENTER PHRASE HERE] that social change cannot always be legislated from the top-down*.

In my mind, it's something like the phrase "clarion call", but more of a warning than a call to arms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the phrase you're thinking of is [***cautionary tale***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cautionary-tale). From Cambridge Dictionaries:

> **a story that gives a warning:**
>   *Her story is a cautionary tale for women travelling alone.*

Your title asks for "a warning against doing something", and in your example a real-life example is held up as the warning, which fits the definition quite well. (The phrase also sounds similar to *clarion call*, fwiw.)