# What is a story that uses immoral aspects to give a moral value in the end called?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, story

Is there a specific or related word for when a story illustrates the doing of bad and unlawful things to reveal a moral value beneath it?
For example- a story about a person committing suicide and showing that if anyone had talked to the person, they wouldn't have committed suicide. Or a person with a mental disorder who didn't receive any help from others and was driven insane. I would appreciate any words to describe such a story or an event, thanks!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418315/whats-a-popular-phrase-that-means-a-warning-against-doing-something/418317#418317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a single word but it's usually called a **cautionary tale**

> a story that gives a warning
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cautionary-tale

> A cautionary tale is a tale told in folklore, to warn its listener of
> a danger. There are three essential parts to a cautionary tale, though
> they can be introduced in a large variety of ways. First, a taboo or
> prohibition is stated: some act, location, or thing is said to be
> dangerous. Then, the narrative itself is told: someone disregarded the
> warning and performed the forbidden act. Finally, the violator comes
> to an unpleasant fate, which is frequently related in expansive and
> grisly detail.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cautionary_tale

I would go with the more general dictionary definition. I'm not conviced that the tale has to come from folklore although of course it may.